# How can I refactor this callback hell with Promises?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, callback, facebook-javascript-sdk, promise

I have a block of code that gets a list of my friends friends using the facebook v1.0 API.

```
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1'
  },
  function (response) { // response contains a list of friends
    response.forEach(function(element){ // so for each friend
      FB.api(
        '/' + element.uid + '/friends',
        function (response) { // get a list of THEIR friends
          console.log(response); // and output them
        }
      );
    });
  }
);
```

I'd like to refactor this code to use javascript promises and a .then() syntax that is more readable and maintainable.

To clarify, I do not like the idea of making a `FB.api` call within another `FB.api` call. Especially if I have multiple of these, they can become nested quite deeply.

I'd like to use promises, but I need to be able to pass in the `response` from the previous `FB.api` call.

How can I do this?

Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1'
  },
  function(response){
    return response;
  })
.then(function(friends){
  friends.forEach(function(element){
    FB.api(
      '/' + element.uid + '/friends',
      function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First a small utility function, which serves to promisisfy `FB.api()` ...

```
//jQuery
function FB_api(options) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        return FB.api(options, dfrd.resolve);
    }).promise();
}
```

or

```
//Bluebird
function FB_api(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return FB.api(options, resolve);
    });
}
```

You could similarly use `Q.js` or `when.js` ... .

Now, you can write ...

```
FB_api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, is_app_user FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1'
}).then(function(response) { // response contains a list of friends
    response.forEach(function(element) { // so for each friend
        FB_api('/' + element.uid + '/friends').then(function (response) { // get a list of THEIR friends
            console.log(response); // and output them
        });
    });
});
```